# MacBook Pro mid 2012 screen flicker occasionally

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro mid 2012 screen is flickering occasionally. Please find the screenshot below. Any idea why it is happening, also any workarounds to eliminate it.

[image: pro]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) You can start by [resetting PRAM](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204063).

Comment: That doesn't look like software to me, it looks like either a failing cable or a damaged screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Lets assume that it is problem with cable. Is it possible to replace cable alone??

Comment: afaik, usually it's possible. I don't know details, though - you'd have to check with Apple or a repair shop; which would be the ideal place to do a full diagnosis anyway.

Comment: This looks similar to my late 2011 mpro with the loose graphics chip.  Apple replaced the logic board under a special program since it was a manufacturing defect (even though my Applecare had expired).  @Tetsujin is right - you should have it checked by an authorized shop right away.